# parse hex incoming / create outgoing strings

Tags: c#, parsing, serial-port

I've modified an example to send & receive from serial, and that works fine.

The device I'm connecting to has three commands I need to work with.
My experience is with C.

---

**MAP** - returns a list of field_names, (decimal) values & (hex) addresses
I can keep track of which values are returned as decimal or hex.
Each line is terminated with CR
:: **Example**:

MEMBERS:10   *- number of (decimal) member names*

NAME_LENGTH:15   *- (decimal) length of each name string*

NAME_BASE:0A34  *- 10 c-strings of (15) characters each starting at address (0x0A34)*   (may have junk following each null terminator)

etc.

---

**GET *hexaddr* *hexbytecount*** - returns a list of 2-char hex values starting from (hexaddr).

The returned bytes are a mix of bytes/ints/longs, and null terminated c-strings terminated with CR
:: **Example**::

**get 0a34 10**  -- will return

0A34< 54 65 73 74 20 4D 65 20 4F 75 74 00 40 D3 23 0B

This happens to be **'Test Me Out'**(00) followed by junk
etc.

---

**PUT hexaddr hexbytevalue {{value...} {value...}}** sends multiple hex byte values separated by spaces starting at hex address, terminated by CR/LF

These bytes are a mix of bytes/ints/longs, and null terminated c-strings   :: **Example**:

**put 0a34 50 75 73 68**  - (ascii Push)

Will replace the first 4-chars at 0x0A34 to become '**Push** Me Out'

SAVED OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer previously about serial handling, which might be useful [Serial Port Polling and Data handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124132/serial-port-polling-and-data-handling/15124287#15124287)

to convert your response to actual text :-

```
var s = "0A34 < 54 65 73 74 20 4D 65 20 4F 75 74 00 40 D3 23 0B";

var hex = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("<") + 1).Trim().Split(new char[] {' '});
var numbers = hex.Select(h => Convert.ToInt32(h, 16)).ToList();
var toText = String.Join("",numbers.TakeWhile(n => n!=0)
    .Select(n => Char.ConvertFromUtf32(n)).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(toText);
```

[image]

which :-
  skips through the string till after the < character, then splits the rest into hex string

then, converts each hex string into ints ( base 16 )

then, takes each number till it finds a 0 and converts each number to text (using UTF32 encoding)

then, we join all the converted strings together to recreate the original text

alternatively, more condensed

```
var hex = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("<") + 1).Trim().Split(new char[] {' '});
var bytes = hex.Select(h => (byte) Convert.ToInt32(h, 16)).TakeWhile(n => n != 0);
var toText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes.ToArray());
```

for converting to hex from a number :-

```
Console.WriteLine(123.ToString("X"));
Console.WriteLine(123.ToString("X4"));
Console.WriteLine(123.ToString("X8"));
Console.WriteLine(123.ToString("x4"));
```

[image]

also you will find playing with hex data is well documented at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx

Comment: Much appreciated Keith - I need to plug this in and see what I learn!
Yes - generating the hex shouldn't be so difficult learning new function calls!.  Just starting from scratch on everything at once is something I haven't dome for a (few) years!

Comment: These are what I have to learn!!  SO many pre-canned functions in NET