# C# Serial Port Buffer Looking for Specific Binary Patterns

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have spent a lot of team researching the proper ways to use the serial port in C# such that you don't have problems reading in data.  I think I have a solution which is pretty close to functional, but I have some glitches every once in a while which I cannot seem to figure out.

My goal: Read formatted binary messages from the serial port, and pass them along to a processor.

The message format looks something like this:

> (MSG-HEADER)(MSG-ID)(MSG-LENGTH)(DATA0)(DATA1)(DATA2)...(DATA-N)

Each "word" in the data is 16 bits (2-bytes).  My basic approach is to start in a "read message header" state, where each time the serial data received event occurs, I read from the serial port, store the data in a buffer, and then check to see if I detect the message header.  If I detect the message header, I move into a "read data" state, where I keep reading data into a data buffer until I have read  bytes.

This seems to work pretty well, except occasionally I see "data glitches".  Where I end up storing a message that looks something like this:

> (MSG1-HEADER)(MSG1-ID)(MSG1-LENGTH)(DATA0)(DATA1)(DATA2)(MSG2-HEADER)(MSG2-ID)..etc

Basically, every so often I get a proper message header, message ID, message length, then the data starts (typically around 200 bytes), and right in the middle of that data I see another message header, message id, and message length, and presumably the start of another message data section.  And I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is the code in the serial port data received event I am using:

```
    public byte[] headerBuff = new byte[500];
    public byte[] dataBuff = new byte[500];
    public byte[] tempBuff = new byte[500];
    public int bytesRead;
    public int dataPos;
    public int dataMsgLen;
    public int dataBytesRead = 0;
    public bool READ_HEADER = true;
    ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> serialQ = new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>();


   //private void si_DataReceived(byte[] data)
    private void si_DataReceived(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        //If we're supposed to be reading the header, read some bytes and look
        // For the header identification sequence (0xF989)
        if (READ_HEADER)
        {
            //Read some bytes, save how many we read
            bytesRead = comport.Read(headerBuff, 0, comport.BytesToRead);

            //Any time we call comport.REad, we automatically log those bytes to a file
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(defDataDir, FileMode.Append)))
                writer.Write(headerBuff.Skip(0).Take(bytesRead).ToArray());

            //Loop through the bytes we just read and look for sequence
            for (int i = 0; i < (bytesRead-1); i++)
            {
                if (headerBuff[i] == 0xF9 && headerBuff[i + 1] == 0x89)
                {
                    //We have identified a header
                    // Lets copy it into a new array
                    dataPos = bytesRead-i;
                    Array.Copy(headerBuff, i, dataBuff, 0, dataPos);
                    dataMsgLen = dataBuff[4];

                    //Now we can switch to message logging
                    READ_HEADER = !READ_HEADER;
                    Array.Clear(headerBuff, 0, headerBuff.Length); //clear the buffer for next time
                    break; // don't need to look for headers anymore
                }
            }
        }

        //If we are done reading the header, let's wait until we get 
        // enough bytes to store the data message
        else if (!READ_HEADER)
        {
            // Read some bytes into temp array
            var tempNumBytes = comport.Read(tempBuff, 0, comport.BytesToRead);

            //ADD this into data buffer
            Array.Copy(tempBuff, 0, dataBuff, dataPos + dataBytesRead, tempNumBytes);

            //Increment our counter
            dataBytesRead += tempNumBytes;

            //Save to stream
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(defDataDir, FileMode.Append)))
                writer.Write(tempBuff.Skip(0).Take(tempNumBytes).ToArray());

            //Add to FIFO if we have read enough bytes
            if (dataBytesRead >= (dataMsgLen * 2))
            {
                //Debug.Print(BitConverter.ToString(dataBuff));
                serialQ.Enqueue(dataBuff.Select(x => x).ToArray()); // Add to queue for processing
                READ_HEADER = !READ_HEADER; // Go back to looking for headers
                dataBytesRead = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

I appreciate any help, let me know if you need any clarifications.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where do you have this problem - in serialQ, the log file or both? Furthermore - you can't be sure that the complete header is read, so databuf[4] may fail. And it's not sure either that temBuff contains the rest of MSG1 only. It may have data from MSG2. If I don't overlook something, you skip the rest of tempBuff after reading MSG1 (ignoring the next header).

Comment: There are several mistakes.  Biggest one is serialQ.Enqueue(dataBuff), it keeps putting the same byte[] array into the queue.  You don't know when it will be dequeued.  But your DataReceived event handler just keeps writing to to dataBuff, corrupting the previous frame.   Part will be new data, part will be old data.  You have to copy the frame or allocate a new dataBuff.

Comment: @JeffRSon, I have this problem in the serialQ, not the log file (that seems to be fine as far as I can tell).

Comment: @HansPassant - I suppose I didn't look closely enough at the Queue class, I assumed it made a copy into the Queue, but it sounds like that is not the case.  I will look more closely at it.

Comment: @HansPassant, can you elaborate at all on the other mistakes I've made?  Thanks.

Comment: The header reading code is broken as well.  You can get F9 but not get 89 until the next time DataReceived fires.  This kind of code tends to be much easier to write if you don't use DataReceived but use your own thread to make Read() calls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serial Port Polling and Data handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124132/serial-port-polling-and-data-handling)

Answer (score 0):

All,
Thank you for your comments. Based on what I read, I re-wrote the serial data handler (see code below) and it seems to be working much better. I have had it running for about ten minutes now and I haven't seen this glitch at all.

```
    //Declare some public variables for serial port reading
    public byte[] headerBuff = new byte[500];
    public byte[] dataBuff = new byte[500];
    public byte[] tempBuff = new byte[500];
    public int headerBytesRead = 0;
    public int dataBytesRead = 0;
    public const int HEADER_LENGTH = 10;
    public int dataInd;
    public int fullMsgLen;
    public byte[] queuePop;

    //Declare some states
    public bool READ_HEADER = true;

    //Where will we store the data log?
    public string defDataDir;

    //Declare a public queue as a FIFO for incoming serial data once the 
    // buffer is full
    ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> serialQ = new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>();


   //private void si_DataReceived(byte[] data)
    private void si_DataReceived(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        //If we're supposed to read the headers, do that
        if(READ_HEADER)
        {
            //Read some bytes
            var numBytesRead = comport.Read(tempBuff, 0, comport.BytesToRead);

            //Any time we call comport.Read, we automatically log those bytes to a file
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(defDataDir, FileMode.Append)))
                writer.Write(tempBuff.Skip(0).Take(numBytesRead).ToArray());

            //Add these bytes to a header array
            Array.Copy(tempBuff, 0, headerBuff, headerBytesRead, numBytesRead);

            //Increment headerBytesRead counter
            headerBytesRead += numBytesRead;

            //Loop through header and see if we have a header
            if(headerBytesRead>=HEADER_LENGTH)
            {
                //Loop through all the header bytes read so far
                for(int i=0; i<headerBytesRead;i++)
                {
                    //Look for the header start word.  Note, 3rd bool statement
                    // here is to make sure we have enough bytes left to identify a header
                    // e.g. read 12 bytes, and bytes 11 and 12 are 0xF9 and 0x89, then we 
                    // clearly don't have the rest of the header (since it is length 10)
                    if(headerBuff[i]==0xF9 && headerBuff[i+1]==0x89 && (headerBytesRead-i-1)>=9)
                    {
                        //We have identified a header, and have enough following characters to save it
                        //Copy the header into the data array
                        Array.Copy(headerBuff, i, dataBuff, 0, headerBytesRead - i);
                        dataInd = headerBytesRead - i;

                        //Save the message length
                        fullMsgLen = dataBuff[4]*2 + HEADER_LENGTH;

                        //Switch over to reading data
                        READ_HEADER = !READ_HEADER;

                        //Reset our header length counter
                        headerBytesRead = 0;

                        //Clear the header buffer for next time
                        Array.Clear(headerBuff, 0, headerBuff.Length); 
                        break; // don't need to look for headers anymore
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Handle reading data into buffer here
        else if (!READ_HEADER)
        {
            //We've just been told to start reading data bytes, and we know how many
            var numBytesRead = comport.Read(tempBuff, 0, comport.BytesToRead);

            //Any time we call comport.Read, we automatically log those bytes to a file
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(defDataDir, FileMode.Append)))
                writer.Write(tempBuff.Skip(0).Take(numBytesRead).ToArray());

            //Add these bytes into the data array
            Array.Copy(tempBuff, 0, dataBuff, dataInd+dataBytesRead, numBytesRead);

            //Increment our data array counter
            dataBytesRead += numBytesRead;

            //Check to see if we have saved enough
            if((dataInd+dataBytesRead) >= fullMsgLen)
            {
                //Copy the header+msg into the queue
                serialQ.Enqueue(dataBuff.Skip(0).Take(fullMsgLen).ToArray());

                //Copy the remaining bytes back into the header buffer
                Array.Copy(dataBuff, fullMsgLen, headerBuff, 0, dataInd + dataBytesRead - fullMsgLen);
                headerBytesRead = dataInd + dataBytesRead - fullMsgLen;

                //Reset data bytes read countery
                dataBytesRead = 0;

                //Switch back to looking for headers
                READ_HEADER = !READ_HEADER;
            }
        }

    }
```